# Congruence of 3 Equilateral Triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles, recreational-mathematics, education

I've been having some trouble with this question from my geometry booklet, any help would be appreciated

*Let ABC be an acute-angled triangle. To the outside of triangle ABC attach equilateral triangles ABD, BCE and CAF, prove that line segments AE, BF and CD all have equal length*

Thank you in advance!

Edit: I have tried to learn the Menelau's Theorem in order to attempt this question but did not see any relevance, I have learnt that they all intersect at the same point but am unable to describe that in mathematical terms

Comment: Please add to your post what you have tried. Only then I can answer. That's the rule here.

Comment: thank you for informing me, I am new here and did not know

Comment: It is not true that they have the same midpoint, but they are indeed all concurrent at a special point known as the fermat point.

Comment: sorry, i worded it incorrectly in the question, thank you for that I will research the Fermat point, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach:

$\triangle CBF=\triangle CAE$ for SAS(two sides and angle between are equal).So $AE=BF$. For the similar reason $\triangle BCD=\triangle BAE$ so $AE=CD$ , therefore $AE=BF=CD$.

Comment: thank you so much for this, i am more experienced with this method and understand it alot

Answer (score 4):

We will prove that $BF$ and $CD$ have the same length. By symmetry, this will imply that $AE$ has equal length to the other two.

Note that clearly $B$ is a rotation of $D$ centered about $A$ by $60^\circ$ clockwise (assuming WLOG the vertices of $\Delta ABC$ are marked counterclockwise) and $F$ is a rotation of $C$ centered about $A$ by $60^\circ$ clockwise.

Hence, $BF$ is a rotation of $CD$ centered about $A$ by $60^\circ$ clockwise. Since rotations preserve length, we have that $BF=CD$.

Comment: thank you so much, this was really helpful

Comment: Nice @alan, this was a brilliant argument!